# Qt QWidget transparent background fails on Android

Tags: android, background, qt5, transparent

When I attempting to set transparent background for QWidget in Qt for Android, it ends up with a background filled with the blurred texture of what behind unexpectedly.

The code below is what I write to give the QWidget a transparent background in Qt for Android:

```
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

But unexpectedly, it ends up showing as follows: (The blurred rectangle is actually the transparent QWidget)

[Screenshot here](https://cdn.luogu.com.cn/upload/image_hosting/b9o9554c.png)